# Output "<"/">" Character in HTML

Tags: php, html, special-characters

I'm trying to display "<"/">" as String in HTML not as a tag.

I have a database that contains user's Fullname and Email and when I want display them both I have a format like this:

`Christian Eric Paran <CEPexample@yahoo.com>`

but I it only display like this:

`Christian Eric Paran`

is there a way to Display this in HTML from PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Represent characters with special meaning (`<` → `&lt;` & `&` → `&amp;` being the ones you need to worry about in text nodes) in HTML using [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2).

The [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function will convert for you.

```
print htmlspecichars("Christian Eric Paran <CEPexample@yahoo.com>");
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem is, the `<` and `>` are used by HTML to delimit tags.  The email address thus ends up parsed as an HTML tag, and ends up hidden by most if not all browsers.

Use `&lt;` to display a `<` in HTML, and `&gt;` for `>`.

If the data will be dynamic, use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` to do the above encoding for you prior to printing it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to the appropriate HTML entities - such as '`&lt;`'

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with email address am sure you would need some flexibility dealing with how you display the result it not just hiding the tag

I would recommend   http://php.net/mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses

```
   $email = mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses("Christian Eric Paran <CEPexample@yahoo.com>") ;
   echo $email[0]['display'] ; // Christian Eric Paran
   echo $email[0]['address'] ; // CEPexample@yahoo.com
```

If you don't have mail parse installed you can use this

```
$email = parse_addresses ( "Christian Eric Paran <CEPexample@yahoo.com>" );
echo $email ['display']; // Christian Eric Paran
echo $email ['address']; // CEPexample@yahoo.com
```

`parse_addresses` function

```
function parse_addresses($address) {
    $info = array ();
    preg_match_all ( '/\s*"?([^><,"]+)"?\s*((?:<[^><,]+>)?)\s*/', $address, $matches );
    $info ['display'] = $matches [1] [0];
    $info ['address'] = str_replace ( array (
            "<",
            ">" 
    ), "", $matches [2] [0] );

    return $info;
}
```